# (Java) If and else if statements don't recognise strings

Tags: java

Sorry if the question doesn't make much sense, I'm very new to Java. So here's my problem: I'm making a text adventure game (very basic at the moment) and I created a string (choice1), which is equal to the answer the player gives to a question the game asks. The answer is either supposed to be north, North, south or South. When I found that no matter what I typed it said it was an invalid answer, I made the game display what choice1 was equal to when I typed my answer. I found that when I typed north, it displayed north, when I typed south, south, etc. So it had correctly picked up what I had typed, but it still said it was an invalid answer. Here is my code (including the part that displays what choice1 is equal to):

```
Scanner answer = new Scanner(in);
String choice1 = answer.nextLine(); 

out.println(choice1);
if (choice1 == "north" || choice1 == "North") //If the answer is North
{
    out.println("You start walking towards the mountains in the distance. A cold wind picks up from behind you.");  
}

else if (choice1 == "south" || choice1 == "South") //If the answer is south
{
    out.println("You head into the forest and are quickly surrounded by trees. Patches of light dance on the floor to the whim");
}

else if (choice1 != "south" || choice1 != "South" || choice1 != "north" ||     choice1 != "North") //invalid answer 
{
out.println("Please enter a valid answer.");
}

answer.close();
```

Comment: As per your code requirement, I guess you want to use && instead of || for the last else if statement. As In your case, if any one of those conditions will be true then it will show "invalid answer". 

For eg:
If you provide "north" as input it will not be equal to "south", "South" or "North" and else if condition will result in true and it will print invalid answer.

Comment: Instead of `if-else`, you could consider a `switch-case`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) instead of `==` to compare [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)s. For a case insensitive comparison, use [`String#equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

Get use to read the documentation,  you can't use == to compare Strings , if you look at Java's documentation you will find the method

```
  boolean equals(String s)
```

How to use :

```
  if(choice1.equals("whatever"))
  {
       // TODO the jobe here
  }
```

Comment: You **can** use `==`. Otherwise, the compiler wouldn't allow you to do so. I would say you **should not** or **must not**.

Comment: `choice1.equals("whatever")` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `choice1` is `null`. To avoid it, use `"whatever".equals(choice1)`.